# Is my exam board correct in saying that a variable is a condition?

Tags: algorithms

A question given in an exam goes as follows:

> A student is tracing the following algorithm-
>
> 1. Start
> 2. Input N
> 3. Let A=1, B=1, C=0
> 4. Let C = C+A
> 5. Let D = A +B
> 6. Print A
> 7. Let N = N-1
> 8. If N !=0, Let A = B, Let B = D, GOTO 4
> 9. Print C
> 10. Stop
>
> (a) Trace the algorithm with N=5
>
> (b) Explain the role of N in the algorithm

The mark scheme says -

> N is used as a stopping condition.
>   But not simply 'a counter'

I would argue that N is a counter.

The condition is 'N = 0'
N is an operand in this condition, but it is not a condition in itself.
A condition would have to evaluate to a boolean value, which N is not.

Comment: Is the condition in step 8 really supposed to be $N=0$? As written the loop will execute exactly 2 times if the input is $1$, and exactly once for any other input.

Comment: Yes, It is N=0.

Comment: x @Theo: In that case I don't see any real grounds for calling $N$ a counter. It doesn't seem to count anything.

Comment: It counts the number of times that the body of the algorithm should repeat.

Comment: x @Theo: No it doesn't. It _would_ count number of repeats if the condition was $N\ne 0$ -- but when the condition is $N=0$ the loop will run _exactly twice_ when the input is $1$ and _exactly once_ for _every other input_.

Comment: Sorry, see my edit. If N =0, the algorithm continues to step 9, otherwise it loops again.

Comment: I will upload an image

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are right in that $N$ is a counter for how many times the program has left to go through the body loop. However, I think your answer sheet is trying to tell you that it is more than a counter: It is also a stopping condition. When $N=0$, the program stops. Otherwise, the program keeps going. This is a common technique for numbers to actually be used as Booleans instead of like numbers. In fact, I would write this would be written in C code:

```
if (N) {
    A = B;
    B = D;
    goto label; //Line 4
}
```

Notice how I did not right `N != 0`. While that would be more clear and readable code, I don't need to do that because that's how C and most other programming languages process numbers as conditions. Therefore, `N` can be used as both the stopping condition and a counter.

Comment: Crap, I wrote it the wrong way around. If N=0, it goes to step 9, otherwise it loops.

Comment: @TheoPearson-Bray I edited my answer to explain how `N` is both a counter and a stopping condition.

Comment: Ok. I didnt release that was valid syntax. At least in Java, unless the value is a boolean, there needs to be an operator to form a condition.

Comment: I suppose that as the exam pseudocode has no strong typing, any variable could be used as a condition.